# HttpLib2 Works in Python 2 but not in Python 3 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I have a program I'm converting from python 2.7 to python 3.3. Everything works perfectly in 2.7, but in 3.3 I keep getting:

```
ImportError: No module named 'httplib2'
```

Now, I have httplib2 installed, and like I said, it works in python 2.7. The 2.7 version of the program and the 3.3 version are in the same directory, so I wouldn't think that would affect it. Anyone know what the issue is here?

The only relevant code snippets are:

```
import httplib2
from httplib2 import FileCache
```

Comment: Do you have it installed on Python3?

Comment: Maybe this is going to sound stupid, but I installed the library in the terminal and all I did was type 'python install setup.py'. So, how would I install it for python 3 specifically?

Comment: If you have `setuptools` in Python3 I would try `python3 install setup.py`

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? The OP deserves an explanation!

Comment: I think I have setup tools, but that command gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it to install finally, but I got this error when running the program now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kevin/Documents/UROP/googletranslator3.py", line 81, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 897
    print "connect: (%s, %s) ************" % (self.host, self.port)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try going to terminal and running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-httplib2
```

I know you said you already had it installed, but I was getting the same error and the above resolved it.

**Edit:** Sorry, I see now you're on OSX. Can you translate the above to the proper command for Mac?

Comment: I get the error 'sudo: apt-get: command not found'. I think this is because OSX does not have sudo installed on it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forget that OSX's terminal is different. Let me try and find the equivalent.

Comment: Actually I think I got it to install somehow, but I now get this error when running the program: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kevin/Documents/UROP/googletranslator3.py", line 81, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 897
    print "connect: (%s, %s) ************" % (self.host, self.port)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hmm...odd. Perhaps related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=75)?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, that means `httplib2` is not installed into your Python 3 installation. Someone recommended you try this:

```
sudo python3 install setup.py
```

You mentioned that you got an error—for good reason. `python3` takes the filename *first*. The command *really* should have been

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Installing it this way or in another approved way (say, `easy_install-3.3` or `pip-3.3`) is required. The error you got installing it a different way suggests your installation skipped the `2to3` step, without which the package will contain Python 2 code, which Python 3 will occasionally choke on. Try uninstalling it the previous way and installing it this way.